# Importing external bookmark (.dat) files into many MXDs using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, bookmarks

Does anyone know any python script to use  for arcview to import a bookmark (saved as a .dat) that was created and saved externally using ArcMap?
I tried with this script but without a result:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"F:\Projects\Roni\abaloa"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"F:\Projects\Roni\abaloa\\" + mxdname)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    arcpy.LoadSettings("F:\Projects\Roni\abaloa\gis\layers\b1.dat")
    for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, 'Bookmark1', df):
        df.extent = bkmk.extent
 mxd.save()
 del mxd
```

I've also searched all documentation and forums with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

As PolyGeo outlined, you cannot transfer bookmarks from one map document to another with arcpy. What you can do, however, is:

1. You can list your bookmarks in a map document with arcpy.ListBookmarks function (you will get name and extent). The extent information can be used to create features which you can save into a feature class (at least something).
2. You can use ArcObjects to create bookmarks based on the extent information you have obtained. See [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000020000000) and [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002w1000000) to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

The function that you tried i.e. [LoadSettings (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000045000000) will load Geoprocessing environment settings:

> Loads environment settings from an environment settings file (text
>   stored in an Extensible Markup Language [XML] schema).

but Bookmarks are stored with the properties of a Data Frame object and so will not be altered by that.

However, there is an existing ArcGIS Idea entitled [Create Bookmark Toolbox](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000brMVAAY) that, if implemented, would deliver the functionality that you seek.

Consequently, I recommend that you add your vote to it.